# Finding Second Lowest Value within a Joined Pair SQL (using rank)

Tags: mysql, join, min, rank

So my general problem is this I have two columns order.delivery_date and user_profiles.users and I need to find the second delivery date (aka the second to last value from the minimum) for each user.

I have tried two solutions. The first was to try and exclude the minimum value as follows:

```
SELECT user_profiles.users, min(orders.delivery_date) FROM orders
 LEFT JOIN user_profiles ON user_profiles.user=orders.user_id
 WHERE orders.delivery_date NOT IN (SELECT user_profiles.users, 
  min(orders.delivery_date) FROM orders
  LEFT JOIN user_profiles ON user_profiles.user=orders.user_id
  GROUP BY user_profiles.users)
GROUP BY user_profiles.users
```

This for obvious reason was not a good solution

I then tried to create rank with in each user for their delivery dates. So that way all I had to do was select rank 2 for each user. However I couldn't generate the ranks. My code is follows:

```
SELECT    orders.delivery_date, user_profiles.user,
( 
            CASE orders.delivery_date 
            WHEN @curType 
            THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
            ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := orders.delivery_date END
          ) + 1 AS rank
FROM      orders,
          (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '') r
LEFT JOIN user_profiles ON user_profiles.user=orders.user_id
```

Every time I tried to run this it gave me this error: Unknown column 'orders.user_id' in 'on clause'

Any ideas for how to solve my rank issue or my general problem would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simple rule:  Never use commas in the `from` clause.

Write the second query using `cross join`:

```
SELECT o.delivery_date, p.user,
       (CASE o.delivery_date 
             WHEN @curType 
             THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
             ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := o.delivery_date
        END) + 1 AS rank
FROM orders o LEFT JOIN
     user_profiles p
     ON up.user = o.user_id CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '') vars
ORDER BY p.user, o.delivery_date;
```

Note that when you use the variables method, you should have an explicit `order by`, because the mechanism requires the data in a particular order.  Your logic is also incomplete, because multiple users with one order and the same delivery date will not be counted correctly.